# Has something changed recently with tensorflow installation process?

Tags: tensorflow, pip

Trying to install tensorflow on mac.

Just created a virtual environment, with python 2.7.10. then i did

```
"pip install tensorflow"
```

I get

```
"No matching distribution found for tensorflow"
```

Did this so many times in past. Even tried pip3
Same results. I dont want tensorflow-GPU

Comment: What do you get if you run `python -c "import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())"`? Looking at [the PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) it seems there is the file `tensorflow-1.7.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl` for Python 2.7 in OSX 10.11.

Comment: macosx-10.10-intel

Comment: It seems to be the case that platform tag in OSX has caused some problems in the past, as it can end with `x86_64` or `intel` depending on your Python distribution (see [here](https://github.com/MacPython/wiki/wiki/Spinning-wheels)), and in principle an `intel` package can be installed in `x86_64` but not the other way around (this case). [Pip issue #1465](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1465) has a long discussion about it. However, it seems an updated version of Pip should work. Did something in your environment change? Or maybe you could try to update Pip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that grpcio== 1.10.0 is broken. 
[image: grpcio error]
Check this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17369) on github

**Solution**:

Try:

```
 pip install grpcio==1.9.1 tensorflow
```

If this does not work then try

```
pip install grpcio==1.9.1 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

For me second step worked. Hope this helps